# undefined method in gateway

Tags: php, oop, opencart

i'm creating a custom gateway module for opencart but i have some problem in the code.
can you please tell me what i do wrong?

opencart debugger shows error:

```
[03-Oct-2013 06:50:02 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ControllerPaymentMyBank::check_order() in /home/***/public_html/catalog/controller/payment/mybank.php on line 207
[03-Oct-2013 06:50:34 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ControllerPaymentMyBank::ResponseToBank() in /home/***/public_html/catalog/controller/payment/mybank.php on line 225
```

the function what i use:

```
public function callback() {

        //SOME CODE HERE WORKS....


        $xml = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
                   xml_parse_into_struct($xml, html_entity_decode($_POST['ConfirmRequest']), $vals);
                   xml_parser_free($xml);

                  foreach ($vals as $data)
                          {
                           if ($data['tag']=='STATUS')
                           $Status=$data['value'];
                           if ($data['tag']=='PAYMENTID')
                           $PaymentId=$data['value'];
                           if ($data['tag']=='PAYMENTDATE')
                           $PaymentDate=$data['value'];
                           if ($data['tag']=='TRANSACTIONID')
                           $TransactionId=$data['value'];
                           if ($data['tag']=='AMOUNT')
                           $Amount=$data['value'];
                           if ($data['tag']=='REASON')
                           $Reason=$data['value'];
                       if ($data['tag']=='CARDTYPE')
                           $CardType=$data['value'];

                          }


                    if($Status=='C')
                    {
                    if($this->check_order($TransactionId,$Amount))
                    $this->ResponseToBank($TransactionId,$PaymentId,'ACCEPTED');             
                    else
                    $this->ResponseToBank($TransactionId,$PaymentId,'DECLINED');   
                    }


                    if($Status=='Y')                             
                      {

                           if( $this->success_order($TransactionId) )
                                             $this->ResponseToBank($TransactionId,$PaymentId,'ACCEPTED');   
                                                        else
                                  $this->ResponseToBank($TransactionId,$PaymentId,'DECLINED');

                    }


                    $this->ResponseToBank($TransactionId,$PaymentId,'ACCEPTED');      


                    function ResponseToBank($TransactionId,$PaymentId,$Status)
                             {

                                         $xmlstr = "<ConfirmResponse>";
                                         $xmlstr .= "<TransactionId>".$TransactionId."</TransactionId>";
                                         $xmlstr .= "<PaymentId>".$PaymentId."</PaymentId>";
                                         $xmlstr .= "<Status>".$Status."</Status>";
                                         $xmlstr .= "</ConfirmResponse>";

                                        header('Content-type: text/xml');
                                        die($xmlstr);
                                 }            





                    function check_order($orderid,$amount)
                              {
                                    return true;

                              }



                    function success_order($orderid)
                              {


                                return true;

                              }




    }
```

how i can define those method right?

Comment: Jesus in Heaven, please, make sure Your PHP skills will make MUCH MUCH better before You will write anything for OpenCart... And especially if this is a payment gateway!!!

Comment: is your super puper style adding the negative points? if you don't like something just close the thread mr. brain

Comment: I give negative as well as positive points. I gave positive points to both answers here as they are good, but I gave a negative point to Your question for these reasons: you are not *demonstrating a minimal understanding of the problem being solved*, IMHO this question is not a benefit to the community, and the code looks awful so I don't want other *developers* to take example of it. I hope I explained this clear. If You see my account You'll find out that from 1051 votes I gave **only** 124 downvotes while 708 upvotes... So no, this is not my style unless I feel a downvote is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the methods inside the `callback` function. Move these outside this function to make them part of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something, this is a plain PHP syntax question. If you do this:

```
$this->check_order($TransactionId,$Amount)
```

... that assumes that you have a class method in current class:

```
class ControllerPaymentMyBank{
    private function check_order($orderid, $amount){
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, you have a regular function that happens to be defined inside another class method:

```
class ControllerPaymentMyBank{
    public function callback()
        function check_order($orderid,$amount){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

That's not pure object-oriented programming, it's a mixture of OOP and procedural code that's equivalent to:

```
class ControllerPaymentMyBank{
    public function callback()
    }
}

function check_order($orderid,$amount){
    return true;
}
```

Define `check_order()` as a proper class method and you should be done.